# How to sort email by time in imaplib using python

Tags: python, imaplib

I would like to sort the emails by arrival time.

Here is the code:

```
data = get_credential('info.txt')
imap_conn = create_connection(data, 'outlook.office365.com')
imap_conn.select('INBOX', readonly=False)
result, messages = imap_conn.sort('ARRIVAL', 'UTF-8', 'FROM peter@gmail.com SINCE "'+(datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(4)).strftime('%d-%b-%Y')+'"
```

It returns the following error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\imaplib.py", line 794, in sort
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, sort_criteria, charset, *search_criteria)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\imaplib.py", line 1196, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\imaplib.py", line 1027, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.IMAP4.error: SORT command error: BAD [b'Command Error. 12']
```

How to solve the problem?

Is the input charset `UTF-8` correct? How to get it from `messages`?

Comment: Quick googling indicates that "Command Error 12" is just Microsoft's way of saying "things we make don't work so well". Does your code work against another IMAP server which is not Exchange or similar?

Comment: As an aiide, passing `None` as the character set parameter seems to be a widely obeyed convention. You don't have any non-ASCII sequences in your search command anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office365 doesn't support the `SORT` extension.

`* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CLIENTACCESSRULES CLIENTNETWORKPRESENCELOCATION BACKENDAUTHENTICATE CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+`

You should check `CAPABILITY` before using any extensions.